# What are the essential pure mathematics branches applied in theoretical high energy physics

Tags: particle-physics, mathematical-physics, education

I am a physics graduate student.I am interested in theoretical high energy physics.Very often people say that to be a good theoretical physicist you need to know mathematics very well.Now although we take courses in mathematics in college but most of the courses were taught in limited way.Mathematics is a huge subject but depending on my interest (theoretical high energy physics) I think I can figure out how much mathematics I really need to learn carefully.But I can't figure out which part is necessary and which is not.I wonder if someone can help me with a flowchart of various mathematical branches from very elementary level to some advanced level which I need to study.You can also suggest me online sources.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35702/2451 and links therein.